# getContentLength returning 1225, real length 3365

Tags: java, android, json, https

I am currently working with android and i am using a http connection with some headers (i havent included them or the real url for security purposes) to get a JSON response from an API, and feeding that response back into the application. The problem that i am having is that when using the getContentLength method of the http request, the wrong length is being returned (wrong length returned is 1225, the correct length in characters of the JSON array is 3365).

I have a feeling that the JSON is not fully loaded when my reader starts to read it, and as such is only reading the loaded JSON at that point. Is there any way around this, possibly using a delay on the HTTP connection or waiting until it is fully loaded to read the data?

```
            URL url = new URL("https://www.exampleofurl.com");
            HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();               

            request.connect();
            int responseCode = request.getResponseCode();   

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                long contentLength2 = Long.parseLong(request.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));

                Log.i("contentLength: ", "Content: " + contentLength2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally don't recommend always relying on "Content-Length" as it may not be available (you get -1), or perhaps affected by intermediate proxy.

Why don't you just read your stream until it is exhausted into memory buffer (say, `StringBuilder`) and then get the actual size, for example :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStream); // inputStream in your code
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line); 
}
// finished reading
System.out.println("data size = " + sb.length());
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

// and don't forget finally clauses with closing streams/connections
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar sir! Works perfectly! I've tried to vote you up but it says i need 15 reputation :/ It's like school all over again.
Thank you very much!